# How to unset navigator.webdriver in headless chrome using selenium?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can i make `navigator.webdriver` disappear in a headless chrome?

`options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Arrays.asList("enable-automation"));`
The above line can make `navigator.webdriver` disappear in a non headless chrome.But it doesn't work with a headless chrome.
I found `evaluateOnNewDocument` from [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) that can set that property just before page to load.But how to achieve the same with selenium?

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
    get: () => false,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did it.i downloaded chrome version 62.0.3202.45 and the corresponding chromedriver . no automatic webdriver property and allow headless download.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use older version of chromedriver.
Chrome driver version 2.34 with Chromuim browser version 63 dont implement navigator.webdriver property.